# Pasar contenido de una lista de un archivo js a otro

Tags: javascript, html, poo

Estoy practicando con un sitio web, creando elementos con js. En index se realiza un evento en el que cuando se apreta un boton "elegir" se selecciona un producto (es un objeto creado en js). Este objeto se guarda en una lista de js (como si fuese un carrito compras) de una clase previamente creada.

Mediante un link el usuario puede acceder a otra pagina "carrito" para chequear que hay guardado en su carrito. En esta pagina tengo referenciado un js en donde mediante una funcion se recorre esta lista (que contiene el producto elegido en el index) para pdoer mostrarlo. Pero la lista esta vacia al saltar a otra pagina, por lo que no funciona.(si referencio el js que declaraba la lista tampoco, ya que aparece vacia la lista al ser declarada cuando ca

Lo solucione utilizando local storage, cuando se guarda el producto en la lista, se guarda en local storage, y luego en pagina carrito hago un getItem para obtener esa lista y la recorro para mostrar el contenido.

Pero estimo debe haber otra forma de pasar el contenido de la lista que guardo elementos en un index y que pueda ser recorrida en otra pagina del sitio. cual seria?

Comment: quizas se hizo largo, la pregunta seria como puedo compartir el contenido de una lista de js, que se creo en un js referenciado en index, para que se pueda recorrer en otra pagina del sitio. (no puedo referenciar ese js del index en esta pagina, ya que me crea elementos que no quiero)

Comment: Me parece que lo mejor es guardarlo en la base de datos (en el servidor), así tendrás los datos disponibles en cualquier parte (cualquiera que entre desde cualquier parte del mundo). Si es para un único usuario, no hay mejor opción que Local Storage.